# Prime numbers between 1 to 100 in C Programming Language

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I want to print prime numbers between 1 to 100, I write my code like the following but when I run it, it starts printing 3,7,11,17....91
Why not the code print 2?
Please help me friends

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    for(int i=2;i<100;i++)
    {
        for(int j=2;j<i;j++)
        {
            if(i%j==0)
                break;
            else if(i==j+1)
                printf("%d\n",i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: because `2%2 == 0`, yo must asume that, '1 and 2' are prime numbers and continue over there

Comment: How and where should I modify my code?

Comment: there are lot of options, but i think that just using `printf("2\n")` before the loops will do....

Comment: Thank you so much! But I don't want to put 2 manual in the code, I want that the code print 2 it self

Comment: @DanielSanchez in fact `i=2` is never tested in `if(i%j==0)` because for the second loop `j=2;j<i`.

Comment: @DanielSanchez "t just using printf("2\n") before the loops will do.." -- And how will that fix it missing 5, 13, and an infinity of other primes?

Comment: @Netwave 1 is NOT a prime number

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The condition `i==j+1` will not be true for `i==2`. This can be fixed by a couple of changes to the inner loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    for (int i=2; i<100; i++)
    {
        for (int j=2; j<=i; j++)   // Changed upper bound
        {
            if (i == j)  // Changed condition and reversed order of if:s
                printf("%d\n",i);
            else if (i%j == 0)
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much... you solved my problem, But you if you please explain your code, writing comments with the code that why we use the 2nd loop and the if else condition and the break statements, I will be really thankful to you

Comment: You want ME to document YOUR code?  (The structure of the code is the same, I merely fixed a small bug.) That is not what StackOverflow is about.

Comment: It was just a request... Anyways Thank You so much dear

Comment: @user7369637 Advice to non-native English user: don't call people "dear".

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
    int i,j;
    int b=0;
    for (i=2;i<=100;i++){
        for (j=2;j<=i;j++){
            if (i%j==0){
                break;
            }
        }
        if (i==j)
            print f("\n%d",j);
    }
    getch ();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

   int i, j;

   for(i = 2; i<100; i++) {

      for(j = 2; j <= (i/j); j++) 
      if(!(i%j)) break; // if factor found, not prime
      if(j > (i/j)) printf("%d is prime", i);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int i,j,k;
    for(i=2;i<=100;i++)
    {
        k=0;
        for(j=2;j<=i;j++)
        {
            if(i%j==0)
            k++;
        }
        if(k==1)
        printf("%d\t",i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a,b,i,c,j;
    printf("\n Enter the two no. in between you want to check:");
    scanf("%d%d",&a,&c);
    printf("%d-%d\n",a,c);
    for(j=a;j<=c;j++)
    {
        b=0;
        for(i=1;i<=c;i++)
        {
            if(j%i==0)
            {
                 b++;
            }
        }
        if(b==2)
        {
            printf("\nPrime number:%d\n",j);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n\tNot prime:%d\n",j);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
      int i, j;
      for (i = 2; i <= 10; i++){
        int isPrime = 1; //true
          for (j = 2; j <= 9; j++){
            if (i != j && i % j == 0){
              isPrime = 0; //false
              break;
            }
          }
          
          if(isPrime == 1){
              printf("\n%d", i);
          }
        }
}
```